# Increased VDI size but chages are not visible in the virtual machine

Tags: partitioning, virtualbox, vdi

I have increased my virtual size when the VDI was dynamic to 125GB using the command:

```
VBoxManage modifyhd Ubuntu.vdi --resize 128000
```

It didn't increase my actual virtual environment. Then I switched from dynamic to fixed and it still didn't change anything...

VDI size:

[image: This is my VDI size]

Virtual size:

[image: This is my virtual size]

Is there a way to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

Because the disk is expanded, but partition is not going to expand automatically. Boot from your ubuntu iso, and use gparted to expand your partition.